# using sencha touch with rails 3.1

Tags: sencha-touch, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I created an example app on how to use Sencha Touch,Rails 3.1, Devise and Mongodb.

I put the Sencha Touch files in public folder, but i would like to know if there is a way to put it in the assets folder, doing it the rails way.

My issue is that everything gets compiled into one big javascript file, and i don't really want the code that is used for the non login part of the app always available.
you can see the source code for the app here: [link](https://github.com/ishmael/sencha-touch-notes)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

move your javascript files to `app/assets/javascripts/views/...view.js` then they will be compiled for each individual view.